# cannot receive udp broadcast packet on android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to receive udp packets being sent from another android machine.II can receive the same packets over java  udp client program however same not working on android. here is my code:

//Main Activity

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Log.v("Main Activity", "intialized started");
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

            mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
            mainWifiObj.startScan();
            Log.v("Main Activity", "MainActivity started");

            clientDatagramReceiver=new ClientDatagramReceiver();
            clientDatagramReceiver.start();


//clientdatagramreceiver class

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.DatagramPacket;
    import java.net.DatagramSocket;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.SocketException;

    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public  class ClientDatagramReceiver extends Thread {
        private DatagramSocket datagramsocket = null;
        private boolean bKeepRunning = true;
        InetAddress serverIP=null;

        public ClientDatagramReceiver() {
            try {
                datagramsocket = new DatagramSocket(7999);
                Log.v("ClientDatagramSender", "Socket Created");
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("ClientDatagramSender", "Socket Unicast SET");
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] messageBytes = new byte[10];

            DatagramPacket packet = null;
            while(this.bKeepRunning) {
                packet = new DatagramPacket(messageBytes, 10);
                Log.d("ClientDatagramReceiver", "RECEIVING PACKET CREATED");
                try {
                    datagramsocket.receive(packet);
                    Log.d("ClientDatagramReceiver", "INCOMING PACKET RECEIVED");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                serverIP=packet.getAddress();
                Log.d("ClientDatagramReceiver", "IP ADDRESS of REMOTE SENDER: " + serverIP.getHostAddress());

                ServerIpHelper.setServerIP(serverIP);

                ClientDatagramSender.killAllThreads();
                Log.d("ClientDatagramReceiver", "STOPPING BROADCAST SERVICE");

                this.bKeepRunning = false;
                Log.d("ClientDatagramReceiver", "RECEIVER CLOSED");
            }
        }
    }
```

It shows log till: "RECEIVING PACKET CREATED" however doenot receive packets.
Any suggestions would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you added " <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />" in manifest file

Comment: yes i have the permissions

Comment: And "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />"

Comment: i have all these4 permissions in ny manifest anything wrong with the code??<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: Could you please post your logcat output

Comment: i am not able to copy logs from log window

Comment: and what is the device?

Comment: device is an android phone

Comment: Don Chakappan: it shows logs till RECEIVING PACKET CREATED

Comment: Try with this to copy logs  "adb shell logcat > log.txt"

Comment: i got the logs..thankss a ton...but cant paste all of them here..

Comment: /Choreographer(  561): Skipped 107 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

V/Main Activity(  920): MainActivity started

V/ClientDatagramSender(  920): Socket Created

V/ClientDatagramReceiver(  920): RECEIVING PACKET CREATED

V/ClientDatagramReceiver(  920): In try area

I/Choreographer(  920): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: Don Chakkappan:would that help at all???

Comment: try creating new datagram socket inside run() method. It is not a good practice to create socket on main thread.

Comment: V/Main Activity(  920): MainActivity started

V/ClientDatagramSender(  920): Socket Created

V/ClientDatagramReceiver(  920): RECEIVING PACKET CREATED

V/ClientDatagramReceiver(  920): In try area

I/Choreographer(  920): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I/Choreographer(  920): Skipped 207 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

D/gralloc_goldfish(  920): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

I/Choreographer(  371): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: @mahi: socket is being created perfectly no issues with that ...but the still i have modified that...still not receiving

Comment: hmm.. try changing socket timeout,something like: socket.setSoTimeout(2000) and then try sending the packet directly to this device using its ip address without broadcast. Also,are u using an emulated device ?

Comment: yes i am using an emulator...

Comment: there is no way you can test this with an emulator ! sorry, try it with a device it will work.